# React fill remaining height without scroll in

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to fill the remaining area on the screen but the *height:100%* property effect is not working.

Notice the red outlined area which is the radius of the border. The highlighted yellow area is the remaining space on the screen which should have been filled:

[image]

Here is the render method of the page. The first Box container is responsible for showing components for the form inputs. The second Box container is not having the desired effect to fill the full page:

```
render() {
    console.log("state: ", this.state);
    const {symbol, fromDate, toDate} = this.state;

    this.updateAPIData();

    return (
        <>
            <Box display='flex' flex='1' justifyContent='space-around'>
                <IndexSelector
                    id='index'
                    value={symbol}
                    onChange={this.onSymbolChange}/>
                <SeriesSelector
                    id='series'
                    seriesList={Form.seriesList}
                    onChange={this.onSeriesChange}/>
                <DateRange fromDate={fromDate} toDate={toDate} onChange={this.onDateChange}/>
            </Box>

            // The below container properties are not having any effect
            <Box height='100%' border='1px solid red' marginTop='50px'>
                <Graph instructions={this.getInstructions()} apiData={this.apiData} />
            </Box>
        </>
    )
}
```

One approach I have tried is setting the *Box* height to *100vh*:

```
<Box height='100vh' border='1px solid red' marginTop='50px'>
   <Graph instructions={this.getInstructions()} apiData={this.apiData} />
</Box>
```

But this creates a scrollable page. 75vh fills the remaining area without creating scroll-bar. But this is a manually calculated value. Adding a custom viewport size to each page is not scalable. What is the right way to deal with this issue?

EDIT:
Here is the index.css file:

```
html, body, #root, #root > div {
  height: 100vh
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
  monospace;
}
```

Comment: Did you try 'height: -webkit-fill-available'?

Comment: can you share whole code via link? @conquester

Comment: Adding a codepen means adding all the dependencies and the code. This is the render function which is the only place in the code where styling happens.

Comment: You should add `height: 100vh` to a top level element outside your components, maybe even in <body>. Make sure there are no paddings or margins in body either. And then you can set the children's height to 100%. Notice that you'll need to have a 100% height for every child between body and Box in this example.

Answer (score 0):

#### Body is not 100vh by default

It happens because you body tag by default use as little height as possible: [image]

You need to add `height: 100vh` on your body tag in order to change that. After you may use `height: 100%` to stretch your inner elements

Comment: I have updated the question with index.css file which sets the height of body container. Still the same issue.

Comment: 1) Check margins and paddings. 
2) Check that your Graph can be higher (can use all possible height)
3) Try remove everything else except Graph. May be other elements make this space ( I had similar issues with dropdowns )